# React-Native: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

React-native: I am facing this issue when I am creating a debug build running following command:-
cd android/ 
./gradlew assembleDebug

```
Task :app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.
transform[stderr]: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
transform[stderr]:  1: 00007FF62C36EEE5 
transform[stderr]:  2: 00007FF62C348CD6 
transform[stderr]:  3: 00007FF62C3496E0 
transform[stderr]:  4: 00007FF62C7B0D3E 
transform[stderr]:  5: 00007FF62C7B0C6F 
transform[stderr]:  6: 00007FF62C6FC594 
transform[stderr]:  7: 00007FF62C6F2B67
transform[stderr]:  8: 00007FF62C6F10DC
transform[stderr]:  9: 00007FF62C6FA0B7
transform[stderr]: 10: 00007FF62C6FA136
transform[stderr]: 11: 00007FF62C81F7B7
transform[stderr]: 12: 00007FF62C8F87FA
transform[stderr]: 13: 0000007C3E35C6C1
<=======------> 56% EXECUTING [4m 3s]
> IDLE
> :app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets        
> IDLE
> IDLE
```